# How to count the most duplicated value that may have equal count in Java

Tags: java, arrays, performance, counting

I've input the value by

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String  lines = br.readLine();
    String[] strs = lines.trim().split("");
    int x = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[strs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
    }
```

And I've sorted it already by

```
   int temp = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
        for (int j=1; j < (numbers.length - i); ++j) {
            if (numbers[j-1] > numbers[j]) {
                temp = numbers[j-1];
                numbers[j-1] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Problem is here

```
    int numDup = 0, dupCount = 1, maxCount = 0;
    int previous = -1;
    for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
        if (numbers[i] == previous) {
            ++numDup;
            if(maxCount < numDup){
                maxCount = numDup;
                dupCount = 1;
            }
            else {
                dupCount += 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            previous = numbers[i];
            numDup = 1;
        }
    }
    if(dupCount >= 2){
        System.out.println("more");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(dupCount);
    }
```

---

The problem is I wasn't to use dupCount to count the most duplicated value if it's >=2 is "more".
but the program runs incorrectly.

Example program I prefer

> input = 5 // output = 5
>
> input = 1112223333 // output = 3
>
> input = 01223605504 // output = 0
>
> input = 10003444 // output = more

Comment: Hint... Learn to use a debugger or simple print statements to exactly understand what your code IS doing. Then match that against your thoughts what it SHOULD be doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it using `Map` and `Collections`. Given below is the program with sample tests:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        printDupCount("5");
        printDupCount("1123321233");
        printDupCount("01223605504");
        printDupCount("10440034");
    }

    static void printDupCount(String lines) {
        String[] strs = lines.trim().split("");
        int[] numbers = new int[strs.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
        }

        // Put the count of each number into a map
        Map<Integer, Integer> groupMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int n : numbers) {
            if (groupMap.containsKey(n))
                groupMap.put(n, groupMap.get(n) + 1);
            else
                groupMap.put(n, 1);
        }

        // Find the maximum count
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> maxEntry = null;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : groupMap.entrySet()) {
            if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0) {
                maxEntry = entry;
            }
        }

        // Find the frequency of maximum count
        int freq = Collections.frequency(groupMap.values(), maxEntry.getValue());

        // Check if the frequency of maximum count matches with that of any other count
        boolean more = false;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : groupMap.entrySet()) {
            if (freq == Collections.frequency(groupMap.values(), entry.getValue())
                    && entry.getValue() != maxEntry.getValue()) {
                more = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Print the result
        if (more) {
            System.out.println("More");
        } else {
            System.out.println(maxEntry.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
5
3
0
More
```

**Note:**

1. You do not need to sort the number array with this solution.
2. The logic works on the property of `Map` by virtue of which it replaces the existing entry if a new entry with the existing key is put into the it.

Rest of the logic is straight forward. Additionally, I have put important comments inside the code to make it more comprehensible. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues were there

1. In  for loop, you were using ++i instead of i++
2. You need else if block instead of else where maxCount == numDup then dupCount should increase.

```
int numDup = 0, dupCount = 1, maxCount = 0;
       int previous = -1;
       for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
           if (numbers[i] == previous) {
               ++numDup;
               if(maxCount < numDup){
                   maxCount = numDup;
                   dupCount = 1;
               }else if(maxCount == numDup) {
                   dupCount ++;
               }
           }else {
               previous = numbers[i];
               numDup = 1;
           }
       }
       if(dupCount >= 2){
           System.out.println("more");
       }
       else{
           System.out.println(dupCount);
       }
```

Comment: Thanks you ,But i resetting dupCount when their met the new most ,So i use dupCount to determine how many of it. Ex. 10003444 it's need to be "more" because 0 and 4 are equal. but if the Ex. is 1112223333 it's should be only 3.

Comment: Couldn't understand the requirement. Please explain with an example.

Comment: 1112223333 it's should be only 3, please explain

Comment: Because the most count value is 3 i need only most count value.

Comment: you are printing the dupCount then it should be 1 right?

Comment: 01223605504 output 0 why? 2 is repeating twice and 5 is also repeating twice?

Comment: I have updated the answer see if this works for you.